# AJAX send is giving "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"

Tags: ajax, firefox

I know this has been posted before but the answers do not solve my problems. I can't figure out what's going on. The only thing giving an error is 'req.send(null)' which doesn't make sense to me. I'm so confused.

Here's the code I have for my ajax script

```
function changeImg(dir) {
var img = document.getElementById("pic");
var src = img.src.substring(img.src.lastIndexOf("/")+1,img.src.length);
var url = 'ajax/'+src+'/'+dir;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        updateImg(req);
}
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send(null);
}

function updateImg(req) {
var xml = req.responseXML.documentElement;
var src = xml.textContent;
document.getElementById('pic').src = src;
}
```

I'm using jetty with AJAX and I'm testing this on Firefox 3, but I haven't tested the code with my server yet. I can't get passed line 18 -_-

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I've tried moving send, open and onreadystatechange around but it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: [01:10:17.659] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"

Comment: Are you trying to do a cross-site XHR in Firefox 3?